# Calling the last 20 years from csv file on python

Tags: python, linear-regression

I'm trying to call the last 20 years from a CSV file that has the 'date' and 'price' columns on python.

```
df = df[(df['Date']>datetime.Date(1999,1,1)) & (df['Date']<datetime.Date(2019,1,1))]
```

I was expecting the see the data for the last 20 years from 1999 to 2019 alone.

Comment: What output did you get?

Comment: I got the error
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'Date'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you want last 20 years data dynamically whatever the max date will be,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('./your_data.csv')
df['date_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'])
df['year'] = df['date_col'].dt.year
last_20_years = df[df['year'] + 20  >= df['year'].max()]
last_20_years
```